# cpack generates RPMs with %files entries that conflict with the RPM spec. How to fix?

Tags: cmake, rpm, cpack

Recently, I need to ensure that our software can be packaged using `cpack` for RHEL 7 and its free rebuilds (e.g. CentOS 7).  Nevertheless, I have been having an issue that didn't exist for RHEL 6.x and its free rebuilds: the RPMs that `cpack` generates all have in its `%files` section system directory entries like the following:

```
%dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/"
%dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/usr"
%dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/usr/bin"
%dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/usr/share"
%dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/usr/share/applications"
%dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/usr/share/doc"
%dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/usr/share/icons"
%dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/usr/share/icons/hicolor"
%dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable"
%dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps"enter code here
```

which shouldn't be declared by the package.

AFAIK, this requirement has been in the RPM spec for years but only in the recent versions of RPM (i.e. newer than 4.8.0) it is enforced.  Since RHEL 7 bundles with RPM 4.11.1, so what `cpack` generates now conflict with `filesystem-3.2-18.el7.x86_64` with errors like below during a `yum install ...`:

```
file / from install of tunesviwer-1.4-2.noarch conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-18.el7.x86_64
file /usr/bin from install of tunesviewer-1.4-2.noarch conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-18.el7.x86_64
[...]
```

I have tried to use a small `cmake` module consisting of the following:

```
set(CPACK_RPM_SPEC_MORE_DEFINE "%define ignore \#")
set(CPACK_RPM_USER_FILELIST "%ignore /" "%ignore /usr" "%ignore /usr/bin" "%ignore /usr/share" "%ignore /usr/share/applications" "%ignore /usr/share/doc" "%ignore/usr/share/icons" "%ignore /usr/share/icons/hicolor" "%ignore /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable" "%ignore /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps")
```

and include it right before the `CMakeLists.txt`'s `include(CPack)`. But the generated RPM still contains these system directories :(

As a temporary get-around, I have been using a hint given in [File conflict for installing a package with "Filesystem"](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/37185/file-conflict-for-installing-a-package-with-filesystem/), i.e. using the `rpmrebuild` utility to remove these system directory entries in the `%files` section.  Obviously, this is not a fix at all.

Anyone has found a better way?

Comment: For what it worth, if you want to support cmake older than 2.8.12, the last workaround (with the %ignore) works, you just have to put a line break after each of the %ignore strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I couldn't afford to wait. So, looking at the latest `cmake` 3.0.0 release, there is a variable `CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST` that the new release supports with sensible defaults

[Edit] Upon reviewing the doc of 2.8.12, the pair is supported by that older version too.

Since `cmake` source comes with `CMakeLists.txt` files and can generate packages OOTB, including RPM (although I need to tune the settings to fit RHEL's package naming convention, but that's not hard to do), so I simply went ahead first bootstrapped `cmake-3.0.0` with `cmake 2.8.11`, `rpmrebuild -pe` to fix the resulting `cmake` 3.0.0 RPM, `yum` install it, and then use it to do a 2nd bootstrap. Now everything is fine. Problem solved.

My parting thought is that kitware should make its documentation better written. The way a lot of variables is described is dense and even confusing - lacking example is a glaring deficiency.

Furthermore, kitware should eat its own dogfood: provide instructions to build cmake with cmake, not with autotools x-(

Comment: Note that there's also `CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION` if you want to keep defaults.